# why arrows are not working with pdf?

Tags: php, dompdf

am trying to conversion of html to pdf using dompdf. Every thing is working fine. my code  have upwards and downwards arrows in my html like  `&uarr;` `&darr;`. these are working fine with html.

but after conversion on pdf file these are looking with  `?`  only.

am using version dompdf_0-6-0_beta3

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

These particular characters are not supported by the default encoding scheme, which is Windows ANSI. You'll need a Unicode font, plus the correct document format. Luckily 0.6.0 beta 3 includes the DejaVu fonts, which work just fine.

Try: `<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;">&uarr; &darr;</span>`

And ensure that you're set up for Unicode support. I think you should be OK with your version of dompdf, but it never hurts to know the requirements. You can find an [Unicode How-to on the wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo). The information is currently out of date with 0.6.0 beta 3, but it is a useful document none-the-less.